# ZSH: Behavior on Enter

Tags: zsh

I realize, when I'm in my terminal, I would expect to press `Enter` on empty input to make a `ls` or a `git status` when I'm on a git repos.

How can I achieve that? I mean, have a custom behavior on `Empty input -> Enter` in zsh?

---

EDIT: Thanks for the help. Here's my take with `preexec`...

```
precmd() {
  echo $0;
  if ["${0}" -eq ""]; then
    if [ -d .git ]; then
      git status
    else
      ls
    fi;
  else
    $1
  fi;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `[["$1" -eq ""]]` to `["$1" -eq ""]` and putting the code into `precmd` instead of `preexec`.

Comment: Thanks. Updated. If I use `$1`, it is always empty, if I use `$0`, I still get `bad pattern: [zsh`...

Comment: So I echoed the content of `$0`, `$1` and `$2`. Here's what I have `preexec: $0=preexec, $1=ll, $2=ls --color=tty -lh` and `precmd: $0=zsh, $1 = $2 = ""`.  Also important to note: `preexec` is not called when pressing empty string. And `precmd` doesn't know about the previous command. Not sure I can achieve what I want here then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On <kbd>Enter</kbd> *zsh* calls the `accept-line` widget, which causes the buffer to be executed as command.

You can write your own widget in order to implement the behaviour you want and rebind <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
my-accept-line () {
    # check if the buffer does not contain any words
    if [ ${#${(z)BUFFER}} -eq 0 ]; then
        # put newline so that the output does not start next
        # to the prompt
        echo
        # check if inside git repository
        if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            # if so, execute `git status'
            git status
        else
            # else run `ls'
            ls
        fi
    fi
    # in any case run the `accept-line' widget
    zle accept-line
}
# create a widget from `my-accept-line' with the same name
zle -N my-accept-line
# rebind Enter, usually this is `^M'
bindkey '^M' my-accept-line
```

While it would be sufficient to run `zle accept-line` only in cases where there actually was a command, *zsh* would not put a new prompt after the output. And while it is possible to redraw the prompt with `zle redisplay`, this will probably overwrite the last line(s) of the output if you are using multi-line prompts. (Of course there are workarounds for that, too, but nothing as simple as just using `zle accept-line`.

**Warning**: This redfines an (the most?) essential part of your shell. While there is nothing wrong with that per se (else I would not have posted it here), it has the very real chance to make your shell unusable if `my-accept-line` does not run flawlessly. For example, if `zle accept-line` were to be missing, you could not use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm any command (e.g. to redefine `my-accept-line` or to start an editor). So please, test it before putting it into your `~/.zshrc`.

Also, by default `accept-line` is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, too. I would recommend to leave it that way, to have an easy way to run the default `accept-line`.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. Unfortunately, the widget doesn't seem to be executed: If I call `zle -N my-accept-line` manually, with some `echo "test"` before, it is not shown. Calling `my-accept-line` executes, but fails at `zle accept-line` with `widgets can only be called when ZLE is active` (which is normal after some google search)...

Comment: Found the solution here: http://sgeb.io/articles/zsh-zle-closer-look-custom-widgets/ Updated your answer.

Comment: I erroneously bound `^M` to the original `accept-line` instead of `my-accept-line` in the last line of the script. That is why it did not work. Your proposed edit (using `zle .accept-line` instead of `zle accept-line` and overwriting `accept-line` with `zle -N accept-line my-accept-line` instead of `zle -N my-accept-line`) would work, too. Although it would prevent using **Ctrl+J** as fallback.

Answer (score 0):

In my `.zshrc` I use a combination of precmd and preexec found here:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions

I also find that the git-prompt is super useful:

https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt

Comment: Thanks. I'm now struggling with writing the script. Could you check my update?