# Execute command by pressing enter with no input in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This is a PowerShell version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169090/zsh-behavior-on-enter). I would like PowerShell to do `ls` whenever I press <kbd>enter</kbd> without any text typed in the prompt. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code uses [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler) to define a script block to be run on <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You may put it into your `$Profile` file to have it always available.

Tested using Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 7.2.1.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Enter -ScriptBlock {
    # Copy current command-line input
    $currentInput = $null
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref] $currentInput, [ref] $null)

    # If command line is empty...
    if( $currentInput.Length -eq 0 ) {
        # Enter new console command 
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Replace(0, 0, 'Get-ChildItem')
    }

    # Simulate pressing Enter
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```